# Playwright Timeout Error while loading a page

Tags: reactjs, playwright

I have a page in my application which takes 1-2 minute to load and when I try testing it with playwright I keep getting "timed out" error in the Playwright UI. I have tried setting the default timeout to 5 minutes and also used page.waitForLoadState but it's still not working. What should I do?

```
test("my test", async ({ page }) => {
  page.setDefaultTimeout(300000);
  page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(300000);

  await page.waitForURL(/recommended/);
  expect(page.locator('h1:text("test")'));

  await page.waitForLoadState("load", {
    timeout: 300000,
  });
  await page.waitForSelector("button:text('Enroll')");
  await page.locator("button:text('Enroll')").click();
});
```

[image]

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing the page you're dealing with. Please provide an actionable example. But to debug, familiarize yourself with the playwright debug tools: https://playwright.dev/docs/debug

Comment: Is it actually navigating & loading the page ? Can you see it in execution?